# How to check v-data-table element on Cypress

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, cypress

The vuetify v-data-table component has a property called "show-select" that allows you to put a checkbox on every list item. The problem i have is that i need to check any element of the table for a Cypress test, but it haven't worked yet. I gave my table an id and tried using "tbody" element doing something like this:

```
cy.get("#dataTable").get("tbody").eq(1).click()
```

and:

```
cy.get("#dataTable").within(() =>{
  cy.get("tbody").eq(1).click();
});
```

I also tried to use cypress browser tool to try to find the name of the element and it show me something like this:

```
cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(1) > .v-data-table__checkbox > .v-icon')
```

but it didn't worked. I don't know how to do it and would be great if somebody helps me.

Comment: So you need to check the checkbox for all elements or only one element in the table? Also what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't have the HTML for your table so this is mostly assumptions. SO I have looked into a similar vuetify v-data-table with show-select - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#row-selection

Case 1: If you want to select all the checkbox one by one, you can do something like this:

```js
cy.visit('https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#row-selection')
cy.get('td .v-input--selection-controls__input').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).click()
})
```

Case 2: If you want to select any particular checkbox in a row, you can do that by using:

```js
cy.contains('td','Frozen Yogurt').parent('tr').children().first().click()
```

Comment: Thaks for your help, it worked really nice.

Comment: Hey! Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

When testing a table, the HTML is nested like this

```html
<table id="dataTable">                       // table
  <tr>                                       // row 
    <td><span class="v-icon"></span></td>    // column e.g checkbox
    <td>Some text description</td>           // column e.g description
    <td>300</td>                             // column e.g score
  </tr>
</table
```

You want to pick a certain row, you can search for **"Some text description"** in the row.

The checkbox is the `<td>` element before the description, so you can select it with the `.prev()` command

```js
cy.get("#dataTable tbody tr")         // selects all rows in #dataTable
  .contains("Some text description")  // pick the one with this text
  .scrollIntoView()                   // in case the row is not in view
  .prev()                             // get column previous to description
  .click()
```

If you want to select by score

```js
cy.get("#dataTable tbody tr")         // selects all rows in #dataTable
  .contains("300")                    // pick the one with this score
  .scrollIntoView()                   // in case the row is not in view
  .siblings(":first")                 // get first column (checkbox)
  .click()
```

**or** you can specify the sibling that has `.v-icon`

```js
cy.get("#dataTable tbody tr")         // selects all rows in #dataTable
  .contains("300")                    // pick the one with this score
  .scrollIntoView()                   // in case the row is not in view
  .siblings(":has(.v-icon)")          // get column with the checkbox
  .click()
```

If you want to select all rows, you can use `.click({multiple: true})`

```js
cy.get("#dataTable tbody tr")           // selects all rows in #dataTable
  .find('.v-icon')                      // select all the checkboxes
  .click({force: true, multiple: true}) // all rows
```

Comment: I tried this answer and it worked too, thanks for your reply. If somebody else have this problem, this answer works pretty well.